# Looking for a futuristic book with some kids and this weird lady who loves robots

Tags: story-identification, novel

I read this book around 5 years ago. It's got a futuristic setting with the usual - diseases, gene editing, humanoid robots . . .

This is what I remember from it:

- The book cover has some kids on bicycles. I don't remember the number of kids, but they're looking at some bubble (apparently the bubble is there to keep diseases out?)
- The main character is the granddaughter of some rich person (or scientist)
- There's this weird perfect girl that shows up; She has this natural charisma that makes the main character and her friends what to listen to her
- There's this weird mom of one of the friends of the main character that talks about robots and the cloning technology that is possible . . . she focuses upon the new girl with this weird intensity and says something like "You will love this!"
- I think the perfect girl's name started with either an I or an A?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it.

## *The Firefly Code*

[image]

> Mori and her friends live a normal life on Firefly Lane in their utopian community, Old Harmonie. In a world this safe and perfect, they've never had to question anything . . . never had to wonder about how their lives came to be. Until a new girl named Ilana moves in. She's so perfect that Mori and her friends are curious . . . Where exactly did Ilana come from, and why does she act so strange sometimes? When Ilana's secret is revealed, the kids on Firefly Lane must decide: is it finally time to start questioning the only world they've ever known?
>
> In a stunningly imaginative story, critically acclaimed author Megan Frazer Blakemore takes readers on a journey with five friends--new and old--that will have everyone talking about not just what makes people human, but what makes them true friends.

Comment: Don't forget to self-accept.